# Adjoint operator on finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ and $W$ be f.d.v.s over $\mathbb{C}$
and $T:V\to W $ be a linear map and $T^*$ is adjoint operator of $T$ defined by
$$\langle T(v),w\rangle=\langle v,T^* (w)\rangle,\forall v\in V,\forall w \in W.$$

How can I find a linear map $U:W\to V$ satisfying

$$UT(v)=v, \forall v \in \text{range}(T^*),$$$$ \\TU(w)=w, \forall w \in \text{range}(T).$$

Comment: Why such $U$ is possible always, I think you should some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining $U$ to be the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors) of $T$ will give you the desired properties.  I do not know, however, if this is the only solution.